# Definition of $L^1(\mu)$, Lebesgue integrable function with respect to measure $\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

Here is an excerpt from Rudin's  Real and Complex Analysis

[image]

In Defintion 1.31, I am wondering why Rudin writes $f = u + iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are real measurable functions on X **AND** $f \in L^1(\mu)$.

Doesn't $f \in L^1(\mu)$ already give that $f$ is complex measurable, according to Definition 1.30??

So, instead of saying what Rudin says, wouldn't this be enough to say that $f = u + iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are real measurable functions on X and $\int_X |f|  < \infty$.

------------------added----------------------
[image]

Comment: I think when he says $f \in L^{1}(\mu)$ he's just trying to tell us it's integrable.  I understand what you mean that it seems a bit redundant to begin with saying $f$ is complex measurable, but I usually always see people saying $f \in L^{1}(\mu)$ rather than writing $\int_{X} |f| < \infty$.

Comment: anything rude in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that if $u$ and $v$ are real measurable functions that $f=u+iv$ is complex measurable?

Edit, now that you added the other part. It doesn't matter how you say it. What you say is exactly the same as what he says. It's just style. I see $f\in L^1(\mu)$ much more often than $\int |f| d\mu <\infty$.

Comment: Rudin proves that result earlier; I will add that part to my question